# How to dynamically take data into byte-array in python and do the modulation?

Tags: python, groovy

I have a modulation function written basically in `groovy` which is definately `BPSK`.

Below is the `groovy` function.

```sh
private final int HDRSIZE = 5
private final int SAMPLES_PER_SYMBOL = 150
private final float NFREQ = 1/15

private float[] bytes2signal(byte[] buf) {
  float[] signal = new float[buf.length * 8 * SAMPLES_PER_SYMBOL * 2]   // 8 bits/byte, 2 floats/sample
  int p = 0
  for (int i = 0; i < buf.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
      int bit = (buf[i] >> j) & 0x01
      float f = bit == 1 ? -NFREQ : NFREQ
      for (int k = 0; k < SAMPLES_PER_SYMBOL; k++) {
        signal[p++] = (float)Math.cos(2 * Math.PI * f * k)
        signal[p++] = (float)Math.sin(2 * Math.PI * f * k)
      }
    }
  }
  return signal
}
```

`Buf` in the code is the dynamic data. So I used to convert that to `python` using `arlpy`.
Here is the sample code. If i considering below option how can i take my data dynamically ?

**P.S.** I know there is a way to run `python` in `groovy` shell, but unfortunately you need to print everything in the `python` function and that returns the values in `groovy` that you can use. I don't like this as I am dealing with `complex signals`. Is there a work around or more efficient way to do this ?

```py
import arlpy
import arlpy.plot as aplt

bpsk = arlpy.comms.psk()
d1 = arlpy.comms.random_data(100)
x = arlpy.comms.modulate(d1, bpsk)
aplt.plot(x)
```

**Output**

[image: BPSK signal]

But now i feel like i'm missing something and this is not right as `groovy` logic.

Comment: Is your code producing different results (if so, what are they)? Is your
code producing any errors (if so, add it)?

Comment: My code is not producing any errors, I am just bit concern about the logic. I am not so much familiar with groovy (more of the python side). Just confirming my login in python is basically right and the i'm not producing something different than the above code.

Comment: There is a subsectrion on stackexchange for code review. SO is for programming problems. If it works, it's good enough for SO.